# Simplest and chepest way to provide 3.3V@150mA from power supply running at 6Vrms@120mW

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, rectifier, esp8266

I have a power supply that can provide 6Vrms (50kHz) and 130mW max (maybe a bit more). Unfortunately, for my project I need a peak of 150mA in 3.3Vdc (ESP8266) in regular basis during TX but most of the time the consumption will be limited in order to save power supply. 
I heard about supercap and/or battery solution to powerup the circuit but I do not know if it is a valid solution and I would like to keep the circuit as simple/cheapest as possible (and I have limited space/volume) ...
As I have limited knowledge in electronic I need some input from you guys ...

Comment: Your power supply is odd. What are you getting this from?

Comment: I guess we need some more input from you. Without considering the peak current, how are you going to make 3.3Vdc from 6Vrms in the first place? What is the duration of the 150mA peak? What is "in/on regular basis"? Please provide a kind of time schedule. How much voltage drop in the 3.3V is allowed?

Comment: Rectify your input voltage and google "energy harvesting chips"

Comment: Assume two current levels for the ESP8266: one for \$\overline{TX}\$ and one for \$TX\$. We know one of these values. We do not know the other. We also need to know how long of a time you are operating in \$\overline{TX}\$ and how long you are operating in \$TX\$. (I assume you have a filament transformer operating at 6.3 VAC RMS [thereabouts] and will need a bridge rectifier and filter capacitor, perhaps inrush mitigation, and a 3.3 V regulator -- and perhaps that capacitor you mentioned. But you need to write out more details.